# Am I correctly splitting a range input into a separate Svelte component? Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I’m new to Svelte and loving it! Making a single-component app with a few pieces of UI & shared state is ridiculously fun & easy (coming in with an intermediate knowledge of HTML, CSS, & JS, and beginner knowledge of React).

Ultimately, however, I am hoping to make more-complex apps that would involve a lot of inputs & state, so obviously, I need to understand how to use state between components.

However, I am slightly confused about the best way to make a custom input component and best use the state elsewhere. Specifically, I’m look to create a custom-styled `input type="range"` component and use it in a parent.

In the course of writing this question, I did find an approach that seems to work, but I can’t find something in the docs or in Googling that quite matches this case, so I’m unsure of my solution. Here is what I came up with: https://github.com/arrowtype/svelte-slider/.

### A summary of my solution

I started from the SvelteJS Template (https://github.com/sveltejs/template).

**My `App.svelte` is like this:**

```html
<script>
    import SimpleSlider from './SimpleSlider.svelte'

    export let sliderValA = 0;
    export let sliderValB = 15;
</script>

<main>
    <h1>A simple SvelteJS slider component</h1>

    <p>Slider A value is {sliderValA}</p>
    <SimpleSlider bind:value={sliderValA} min="0" max="10" step="1"/>

    <p>Slider B value is {sliderValB}</p>
    <SimpleSlider bind:value={sliderValB} min="0" max="30" step="5"/>

    <p>A + B is {sliderValA + sliderValB}</p>
</main>
```

**And `SimpleSlider.svelte` is like this:**

```html
<script>
    export let value = 5;
    export let min = 0;
    export let max = 10;
    export let step = 1;
</script>

<div class="slider-container">
    <input type="range" bind:value={value} min={min} max={max} step={step}>
    <span>{value}</span>
</div>

<style>
    .slider-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    input {
        margin:0 0.5em 0 0;
    }
</style>
```

In my testing, this seems to work. But, I found it challenging to get there, and I’m unsure of whether this is the best practice.

Should I be doing anything more, like using the `svelte/store` module to handle global state (if not, when might I start to need that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, this looks really good and seems like the way to go for me. Why would you want to use the global store? Using it means having the data everywhere available and saved in your app, which sounds like overkill, when the component is only needed in one little form. Doing it this way is better for small independent components.

There are only little improvements for your *SimpleSlider.svelte* I can think of:

```
<script>
  export let moreProps = {}
</script>

<div class="slider-container">
    <input type="range" bind:value {min} {max} {step} {...moreProps}>
    <span>{value}</span>
</div>
```

This approach takes advantage of sveltes shorthand syntax and reduces your amount of code. `moreProps` would be if you decide to pass additional properties like `disable` for example:

```
<SimpleSlider bind:value={sliderValA} min="0" max="10" step="1" moreProps={{disabled:true}}/>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for pointing out these extra improvements!

Comment: It’s so incredible that Svelte offers that shorthand, and the way to auto-spread in other props.  I guess I may also let `step` go into `moreProps`, as well, as the default step for a range input is just 1, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, update: while putting this into practice, I realize the `moreProps` isn’t a fancy Svelte feature as I initially thought; it’s a variable you instantiate, and then Svelte just allows props to be spread in from that variable. Nice!

Comment: Sorry, one more update:

In a slightly-more complex example, I am trying to listen to the Slider’s events and trigger different handlers based on that (e.g. making value conversions to auto-adjust related sliders). To do this, I have to include "event forwarding" in the Slider component:

`<input id="slider" type="range" bind:value {min} {max} {...moreProps} on:change on:input>`

Comment: Yes, the spread functionality is new Javascript = es6 sytax and it comes pretty handy when you want to pass an unknown amount of props to a component. The good thing is that the underlying component will ignore any props it does not know and does not throw an error.

What does the ```on:input``` do in your case? Shouldn't it be the same as the ```on:change``` handler as you can't input text into that specific component?